# Can an iphone app transparently connect to an https site, using a DER certificate shipped with the app?

Tags: iphone, authentication, https, certificate

I would like my app to connect to an https site, without user input required. So,
I would like to send the app a certificate that the app will install in the keychain,
and allow it to connect to the https site without the user getting involved.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Applications are **not able to install certificates** to the keychain for security reasons.

Otherwise malicious programmers could install a certificate that authenticates phishing sites.

Comment: In theory, applications should be able to install certificates that apply for UIWebViews and NSURLConnections inside the app only, but I'm not sure there's a public API for that.

Comment: From my understanding of the public API, in order to do that you also have to implement your own certificate validation in a subclass of `NSURLConnection` since none of the TLS connection classes are public.